# Change colour scheme of phone specific UI elements (Selected Buttons / Selected EditText)

Tags: android, user-interface, themes

I'm working on a Nexus S and the phone theme uses Black and Orange. I started with a custom button - changing the background from `@android:drawable/btn_default` to my own 9 Patch image. This is fine and dandy and there are 100's of tutorials and examples of such littering Google.

The problem is I don't want to create a different style of button. I want the UI in my app to as insofar as possible to stay true to the phones own buttons and UI elements. What I want is to create a custom button which looks exactly like `android:state_pressed="true"` and `android:state_focused="true"` but instead of orange, blue.

I also want to do this for selected EditText & Spinners and the like.

Am I doomed to backwards engineer each element, guessing each pixel, one for each state and create 9 patch images of them? That's what I've done below for the blue button - as you can see, close but not exact.

Has android given these buttons out somewhere - if that was true it would take an afternoon but it wouldn't be unreasonable to create the same UI set in a different colour.

Or is the a programmatic way of saying "For this app use this theme" that I've just never heard of (Big ask).

[image: Origional Button][image: Sample Button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the Android SDK folder under platforms you will see all of the different SDk levels that you have downloaded.  Inside each there is a data/res/drawable folder where there are all of the images used in the UI.  You can modify those and add them to your own resources.  But yes, any change you want to make to the default UI you will need to implement yourself.

Comment: I could kiss you (but I won't). Amazing.